# Change the position of one label in overlapping points in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the code below `Existing Customers Data` overlap with `Sales History` so display `Existing Customers` data a little bit highRr and more to the right

```
common<-structure(list(criteria = c("Customer Activity", "Existing Customers Data", 
"Prospect Data", "Sales History"), priority.x = c("0.25", "0.27", 
"0.20", "0.27"), priority.y = c("0.25", "0.31", "0.13", "0.31"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
> library(ggplot2)

# Assuming 'common' is your data frame
# Creating the plot
  ggplot(common, aes(x = as.numeric(priority.y), y = as.numeric(priority.x))) +
  geom_text(aes(label = criteria)) +
  xlim(-0.5,0.5) + ylim(-0.5, 0.5) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  labs(title = "Optimization Matrix",
       x = "Feasibility",
       y = "Business Values") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

Comment: Have you looked at the {ggrepel} package for positioning labels so that they don't overlap? You could use `geom_text_repel()` instead of `geom_text()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two alternatives.

You can use geom_text_repel from ggrepl package :

```
library(ggrepl)
ggplot(common, aes(x = as.numeric(priority.y), y = as.numeric(priority.x))) +
    geom_text_repel(
        data = common,
        mapping=aes(x=as.numeric(priority.y), y=as.numeric(priority.x),label=criteria),
        size=4,  box.padding = unit(0.3, "lines")
    )+
    xlim(-0.5,0.5) + ylim(-0.5, 0.5) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
    labs(title = "Optimization Matrix",
         x = "Feasibility",
         y = "Business Values") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

(You can play with the parameters of box.padding)

Or you can just use check_overlap = TRUE in the option of geom_text(). But this will mask some labels.

One last remark, it's a bit weird to have priority.y as x-axis and priority.x as y-axis, maybe you should rename your variables to avoid any mistake.